# C Loops Breaking Clause

Tags: c

this might be a stupid question but i'm having trouble wrapping my head around how this works.

```
//Q8
//Variables
char String[100];
char Yes[] = "Y";
char No[] = "N";
//Coding
do {
    printf("Would you like an ice cream? Y / N\n");
    scanf("%s", String);
} while(strcmp(String,Yes) && strcmp(String,No));
```

Now only one of these return 0, why does the loop break anyway even though it is an AND?

Comment: What is the user input in `String`?

Comment: The program loops until the user enters either "Y" or "N", The program does work properly, my question is why does the while loop break even though it is an AND?

Comment: @Mulliganaceous ... and it will start looping forever. `strcmp` can never return 0 for both calls. Don't forget that `strcmp` returns 0 iff the strings are equal.

Comment: No my question isn't to fix the code, the code works as I want it to, the question was to properly understand what the code does.

Comment: Note that even if you fix the condition, your code doesn't handle EOF properly.  You need to test the result of `scanf()`.

Comment: As mentioned already `strcmp` return `0` if the strings match. A better way to use `strcmp` is to use it with `==0` or `!=0`. In your case, the while condition becomes `while (strcmp(String,Yes)!=0 && strcmp(String,No)!=0)` so you loop while `String` is not `Yes` and not `No`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
while(strcmp(String,Yes) && strcmp(String,No));
```

can be more clearly written as:

```
while(strcmp(String,Yes) != 0 && strcmp(String,No) != 0);
```

It is always better to write it that way, because `strcmp` does not return a boolean, it returns negative, 0 or positive depending if first string comparess less, equal or greater (as strings are compared) than the 2nd string.

It works without that `!= 0` part, because in C zero is false and non-zero is true, so from syntactic point of view there is no difference, the condition is "while String is not Yes and String is not No".

Answer (score 1):

`while(x)` means to continue while `x` is non-zero.

`a && b` evaluates to non-zero if both `a` and `b` are non-zero.

So if either of `a` or `b` is zero, it is not true that both are non-zero. Therefore the loop doesn't continue.

Answer (score 0):

False AND anything is false. If at least one of the `strcmp` calls returns 0, the whole conditional is false and the loop terminates.